# tweetinvi Chunked Uploads for large uploads

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

I am trying to file upload with tweetinvi.File upload work for image but same code does not work for video(large video more  than 20 mb)

I asked here but now answear

[TweetInvi Large Video Upload Failing With Null Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284806/tweetinvi-large-video-upload-failing-with-null-reference)

so I look for another solution.There is tweetinvi chunked uploads 
I coded this but it does not work,it does not give error but it does not work

```
  if (file.ContentType.Contains("video"))//video
                        {

                            var video1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                            var chunk = Upload.CreateChunkedUploader(); //Create an instance of the ChunkedUploader class (I believe this is the only way to get this object)

                            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                            {
                                chunk.Init("video/mp4", (int)fs.Length); //Important! When initialized correctly, your "chunk" object will now have a type long "MediaId"
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[video1.Length]; //Your chunk MUST be 5MB or less or else the Append function will fail silently.
                                int bytesRead = 0;

                                while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    byte[] copy = new byte[bytesRead];
                                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, copy, 0, bytesRead);
                                    TimeSpan s = new TimeSpan();

                                    chunk.Append(copy, chunk.NextSegmentIndex.ToString()); //The library says the NextSegment Parameter is optional, however I wasn't able to get it to work if I left it out. 
                                }
                            }

                            var video = chunk.Complete(); //This tells the API that we are done uploading.
                            listMedia.Add(video); 


                        }
```

Comment: I will investigate your issue. I added the problem on the github website at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/528

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to say that after working on your bug I was able to identify the problem you were encountering.

The issue is that you were not specifying the `media_category` of the upload.

In addition to this you need to wait for the media to be processed by Twitter.

In Tweetinvi 2.1, the process should be made easier. Please use the following code :

```cs
var binary = File.ReadAllBytes(@"video_path");
var media = Upload.UploadVideo(binary);

// The upload is completed but it does not mean it succeeded!
if (!media.HasBeenUploaded)
{
    // Something went wrong during the upload. 
    // Please retry or check the video type/settings.
    return;
}

// Just wait for Twitter to have processed the upload (RECOMMENDED)
Upload.WaitForMediaProcessingToGetAllMetadata(media);

// Now the media is ready to be used in a Tweet
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters
{
    Medias = { media }
});
```

You can read more about the upload in the updated documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload#upload-status-video

Finally please note that further improvements of upload are planned for version 2.2 and 2.3.

Have a great day and thank you for reporting this problem,

Cheers
Linvi